# Is there a javascript equivalent to c#'s .All?

Tags: conditional-statements

Hey Overflow Community,

I'm creating a QC check for duplicate rows in any of 3 tables. I've been running basic conditionals in my chrome console (javascript) then tweaking them to work for my C# script. I found a code block:

`if (new[] { table1, table2, table3 }.All(x => x == 0))`

I'd like to use this to create a conditional for if all values are equal to 0.
Is there a Javascript equivalent to C#'s `.All`? Ideally I'd like to edit this statement to run in my chrome console.

Comment: `myArray.forEach(x => x == 0);` ?

Comment: @R10t-- nice! I’ll try this out. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`every` is the function you're looking for. It has identical semantics to the LINQ's `All`. Your original code would be rewritten as this:

```js
if ([table1, table2, table3].every(x => x == 0))
```

Look for the function's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for more details.